# Find a string in all DataTable columns

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable

I am trying to find a fast way to find a string in all datatable columns!
Followed is not working as I want to search within all columns value.

```
string str = "%whatever%";
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    foreach (DataColumn col in row.ItemArray)
        if (row[col].ToString() == str) return true;
```

Comment: what are you attempting to do?

Comment: Search in all datatable cells for a string, but I want to use LIKE clause and in a faster way too!

Comment: Do it in the database - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/

Comment: @web_bod, thanks, this script will be running on [unknown] datatable in memory, so, I don't know the columns nor do I know the data engine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by filtering. Create a (re-usable) filtering string based on all the columns:

```
        bool UseContains = false;
        int colCount = MyDataTable.Columns.Count;


        string likeStatement = (UseContains) ? " Like '%{0}%'" : " Like '{0}%'"; 
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
        {
            string colName = MyDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            query.Append(string.Concat("Convert(", colName, ", 'System.String')", likeStatement));


            if (i != colCount - 1)
                query.Append(" OR ");
        }

        filterString = query.ToString();
```

Now you can get the rows where one of the columns matches your searchstring:

```
 string currFilter = string.Format(filterString, searchText);
 DataRow[] tmpRows = MyDataTable.Select(currFilter, somethingToOrderBy);
```

Comment: what variable type is `query`?

Comment: A StringBuilder.. Why 2-years-ago-me haven't used the AppendFormat-method, I do not know.. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ. It wouldn't be any faster, because you still need to look at each cell in case the value is not there, but it will fit in a single line:

```
return dataTable
    .Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Any(r => r.ItemArray.Any(c => c.ToString().Contains("whatever")));
```

For searching for random text and returning an array of rows with at least one cell that has a case-insensitive match, use this:

```
var text = "whatever";
return dataTable
    .Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(r => r.ItemArray.Any(
        c => c.ToString().IndexOf(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0
    )).ToArray();
```

Comment: you could make this faster with plinq i think, just add .AsParallel to the query

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight for your reply, but I would appreciate a LIKE clause than "==" because I will be looking for sub-string of the cloumns value

Comment: @meYnot Sure, you can use `Contains(str)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @dasblinkenlight, an error occurred,
'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found

Comment: @meYnot I added the missing `Cast<>`, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks so much @dasblinkenlight for your concern, I am still having an error [Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'] while [c] in r[c] is highlighted, any idea!

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, this is working but "whatever" is fixed and I wanted to return DataRow[] or DataTable in result not bool!
Appreciate your help!

Comment: @meYnot Not sure I understand your last comment, the return statement, actually returns a DataRow[] you can then use the "CopyToDataTable" command to convert it to a DataTable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check every row of every column in your Datatable, try this (it works for me!).

```
DataTable YourTable = new DataTable();
// Fill your DataTable here with whatever you've got.

foreach (DataRow row in YourTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        //Do what ya gotta do with that information here!
    }
}
```

Don't forget to typecast `object item` to whatever you need (string, int etc).

I've stepped through with the debugger and it works a charm. I hope this helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a routine of search with an array of strings with the names of the columns, as well:

```
string[] elems = {"GUID", "CODE", "NAME", "DESCRIPTION"};//Names of the columns             
foreach(string column in elems)
{
    string expression = string.Format("{0} like '%{1}%'",column, 
    txtSearch.Text.Trim());//Search Expression
    DataRow[] row = data.Select(expression);
    if(row.Length > 0) {
        // Some code here
    } else {
        // Other code here
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get names of columns by using ColmunName Method. Then, you can search every column in DataTable by using them. For example, follwing code will work.

```
string str = "whatever";
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        if (row[column.ColumnName.ToString()].ToString().Contains(str))
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a filter expression on the datatable as well.  See this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  Use like in your filter expression.

```
 string filterExp = "Status = 'Active'";
 string sortExp = "City";
 DataRow[] drarray;
 drarray = dataSet1.Customers.Select(filterExp, sortExp, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
 for (int i=0; i < drarray.Length; i++)
 {
    listBox1.Items.Add(drarray[i]["City"].ToString());
 }
```

Comment: He wants to search all columns.