# Search a string in all columns of a data table

Tags: c#

I want to search a string if it exists in a data table and return the rows. For example I have a data table with fields like User Name, User Password,....etc. Now my search text will search all the fields and return me the rows which contains the string.

Can anyone please help on this.
I googled on it.
I found couple of solution, one was

```
Select("Code LIKE '" + lastWord + "%'" );
```

But here I am confused with "Code".

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for value in DataGridView in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173915/search-for-value-in-datagridview-in-a-column)

Comment: Here is the exact question and has good answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661361/find-a-string-in-all-datatable-columns

Comment: `Code` is a name of column. `Select()` is probably applying row filter . [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) is an sql-operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try like following:

```
try
{
  SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from tableName where UserName LIKE '%' + @search + '%'", conn);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search",searchbox.text);
  SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd,con);
  DataSet ds=new Dataset();
  da.Fill(ds);
  //From here you can extract data in DataSet   
}
catch(exception ex)
{

}
```

Can Try SqlMethods.

Do something like where `SqlMethods.Like(str,"%searchbox.text%");`

Can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677799/in-rowfilter-how-to-select-the-all-the-table-columns-in-c?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer.

Comment: I dont want to specify the name of the column. It should search in all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in need of some thing like this http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm from Narayana Vyas. 
I have used it before and it works. It searches all columns of all tables in a given database.

If not, how about this

```
DataRow[] filteredRows =   datatable.Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", columnName, value));
```

OR check [Find a string in all DataTable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661361/find-a-string-in-all-datatable-columns)

---

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be something like this

```
for(int i=0;i<MyDataset.Tables[0].Columns.count;i++)
{

DataRow[] MyDR=MyDataset.Tables[0].Select(MyDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[i].ToString()+"='"+MyText+"'");

   if(MyDr.Length>0)
   {
   //You Found the item
   }

}
```

Hope this helps